# File read from angularjs and convert base64 and push into gitlab

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gitlab

multiple zip File read and display in angularjs and those files convert base64 in nodejs and push into gitlab. please suggest me if it possible in nodejs. is there any blug available for reference.

Answer (score 2):

use fs module of nodejs to read the files from directory

```
const testFolder = './tests/';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
  console.log(file);
});
```

once you get the files you can covert to base64

```
function base64_encode(file) {
    // read binary data
    var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
    // convert binary data to base64 encoded string
    return new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
}
```